# Atualização automática do clock no Matlab

Tags: algoritmo, matlab

Alguém sabe como fazer para atualizar o **clock** no **Matlab**?

Eu só consigo atualizar depois de apertar um botão, mas quero que atualize automaticamente.

Comment: O que você precisa fazer? Não entendi o que realmente você necessita fazer com "atualizar" o clock.

Comment: Quando o horário no meu computador marca 18:00, o led não acende pois quando utilizei o comando clock, era 17:50. Quando pressiono um toggle button, consigo atualizar o clock para o horário atual. Mas eu quero que o clock seja atualizado automaticamente, sem precisar pressionar o botão.